# Should we allow questions regarding the Arabic language?

Tags: discussion, arabic

*(Inspired by the question [What is the difference between NABI and RASUL?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/6))*

Given that the Qur'an and the books of hadith are written in Arabic (and given that [Arabic.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/39256/arabic-language-usage) is nowhere near live yet), should questions pertaining to the Arabic language itself be considered on-topic?

And since there is significant Islamic literature written in languages other than Arabic, where exactly (if anywhere) should such a line be drawn?

Comment: Has there been any discussion here about allowing questions about Islam written in Arabic? (Maybe something like: questions in Arabic can be answered in English or Arabic, but questions in English must be answered in English)

Comment: @DoubleAA Not that I'm aware of. We've just always been a de-facto English-language site even back in the Area51 days. There was an A51 proposal for "Islam in Arabic" a year or so ago, but it died due to lack of activity.

Comment: Using terms and quotes in Arabic language (rather than transliterated or translated) is welcome insofar as they are reasonably understood in context by those involved. But the bulk of the question/answer is still expected to be understood by a primary English-speaking audience.

Answer (score 11):

If someone asks for the translation or meaning of a word or text in Arabic which is relevant in Islam (e.g. Quran, hadith, or other Islamic sources) then that can be considered in the scope and the OP should provide the context to make it on-topic for the site.

On the other hand, the site is not about Arabic language. The translation and meaning of arbitrary Arabic words or texts should be off-topic.

Answer (score 9):

Given how intricately intertwined Islam and the Arabic language are, I think any such line should err on being too far into Arabic language territory rather than not far enough. A rule of thumb that would work for me is for the questioner to provide the link between his/her question about Arabic and Islam, and that would be good enough to merit remaining a question. If no link is provided, nor is there any attempt made, then I would consider that off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Please note the Islamic definition and Islamic difference between two terms are not always the same as Arabic definition and Arabic difference of the same terms.

So if the question is pure asking for Arabic language meanings so it is off-topic. but in fact is asking for something Islamic it can be on-topic here.

Answer (score -1):

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

Did we ever have anything changed on the site because it still shows:

The Arabic language itself

This needs to be changed to provide better details of what in the Arabic language can or cannot be asked. My personal opinion is that any dua, Quraanic ayaat, hadith or any tie with Islam can be asked.

If general Arabic is asked then it should be not be allowed such as asking how to say "how are you doing" in Arabic.

Comment: "The Arabic language itself" is refelecting the 3 other posts. Only interpretation or translation of Arabic terms related to Islam are on-topic if the context is on Islam, aynthing else is a topic of Arabic language itself.

Comment: As Salaamu 3laykum @Jamila , exactly that is my point. But was that reflected in the help section of the Islam stackexchange site. Is that clear on that page? Because I don't find it clear on that page.