# What should our "off-topic" close reasons be?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

As part of the [recent renovation of the Closing system](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/), closing a question as off-topic is now improved in that we can specify exactly *why* it's off-topic in the close reason itself rather than needing to add a comment.

In many cases our default close reason can apply to any scenario, including most questions which are *blatantly* off-topic:

- This question does not appear to be about Islam, within the scope defined in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help).

We also have at our disposal a selection of specific reasons (maximum of three); they aren't intended to list every possible "off-topic" reason, they're predominantly for those topics that may, on their surface, *appear* to fit on this site but which do not for whatever reason.

As of this post, the following two reasons are defined:

- Questions on **Islamic or Arabic culture** unrelated to the beliefs and practices of Islam are off-topic here. See: [Islam SE: Not an Muslim Peer Support Group](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189/islam-se-not-an-muslim-peer-support-group)
- Questions on **politics** are off-topic as they're rarely productive or relevant to the beliefs and practices of Islam.

The default and all three specific reasons are site-configurable.  Are the ones we currently have sufficient?  Do we want to improve on these, or add another one?

Discuss.

---

**Update:** Since this post was written, a third off-topic reason has been added:

- Questions regarding the Arabic language itself, except how they're clearly relevant to the study of Islam, are off-topic: [Should we allow questions regarding the Arabic language?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11/22)

Comment: what is the reference of "Questions on politics are off-topic as they're rarely productive or relevant to the beliefs and practices of Islam." ? I could not find it in help center! political questions are not all the same. some are on topic in Islam and some off-topic. so judging about them all with one rule is not right.

Comment: @BattleofKarbala It's one of the default off-topic close reasons, you can see it if you try to close a post as off-topic (at least on the main site).  And it's been one of the default off-topic close reasons, which were added by the Stack Exchange team, since the off-topic close reason functionality was implemented.

Comment: Does that also apply to political theory in Islam? That is an scholarly field perfectly fit for the site I believe.

Comment: How about "Questions with no non-trivial, core Islam-related issue are off-topic" as per http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/1360/3208 ?

Answer (score 1):

In regards to the second reason:

> Questions on Islamic or Arabic culture unrelated to the beliefs and
>   practices of Islam are off-topic here. See: Islam SE: Not an Muslim
>   Peer Support Group

I believe that Islamic culture is not the words, nor do I believe that "beliefs and practices of Islam" is fitting, rather "Teachings of Islam", I also think that "Arabic culture" should be removed, for that is of course off-topic on here.  So I believe that the reason should be something like:

> Questions on Muslim culture unrelated to the teachings of Islam are
>   off-topic here.  See: [Islam SE: Not an Muslim Peer Support
>   Group](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189/islam-se-not-an-muslim-peer-support-group).

As for the third, I think it should be edited so that it is something like:

> Questions on politics are off-topic as they're rarely productive or
>   relevant to the teachings of Islam.

That would be it in regards to improving them, as for adding anymore, perhaps we can consider adding a reason in regards to sectarianism questions being off-topic.

Answer (score -1):

The “off-topic” close reasons in site software should be same as reasons [declared in help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to site have a clear [terms of use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terms_of_service) and so users not get confused from where these terms declared in closed reason have came from.

> Questions on politics are off-topic as they're rarely productive or
>   relevant to the beliefs and practices of Islam.

This part should be changed. Because Islam has many political aspects and saying politics generally is off-topic does not work about Islam. Islam without its political aspects will not be Islam any more. For example Caliphate, Jihad, Qisas and many more aspects of Islam are clearly political and cannot be removed from Islam.

The off-toic reasons are different in help. [in help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) we see:

> Politics of Muslim-majority countries

Are considered off-topic in this site.

So these two terms have conflict and should become the same.

The software of site should be customized for Islam. The original software of site has been for programming and Indeed politics is off-topic there. But for Islam the site should be changed and customized.

The laws in help center should be base of judgement. And the default terms of software should be base of judgement of mods before customizing the software for Islam site.

Questions about political aspects of Islam should be on-topic and others can be off-topic. Because Islam has its own politics and Islam without its own politics will not be Islam anymore.

If anyone has doubt that Islam is a political religion and has many political laws can ask it in another question to receive enough proofs for that.

So the corrected form of this system close reason can be something like this:

***Politics of Muslim-majority countries are off-topic as they're not necessarily relevant to the beliefs and practices of Islam.***

Comment: This post seems to be full of misunderstandings, not least of which is the idea that we somehow adopted the "no politics" rule from Stack Overflow (of all places), that one is wholly incapable of asking about government/jurisprudence without it being political, or that the help-centre/default-off-topic-list is, or even *should*, somehow be all-inclusive of what is off-topic here.

Comment: so how is "no politics" rule adopted? anyway the two quoted rules in my post have conflict with each other and its better to this conflict solved. anyway is not my suggested sentence better?

Comment: "Questions about political aspects of Islam should be on-topic and others can be off-topic. because Islam has its own politics and Islam without its own politics will not be Islam anymore." u need to make things clear on this buddy.